# gnuplot tikz terminal

Tags: gnuplot, tikz

How do I enable the tikz terminal in gnuplot on Mac Os X(10.6.8)?

I have latex with working tikz. Now I installed lua from http://www.lua.org/ and Downloaded gnuplot4.4.4, unpacked it, and run

```
$ ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

Now I can set the tikz terminal, but there are still problems

```
gnuplot> set terminal tikz
Terminal type set to 'tikz'
Options are 'color dashed'
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot]
         /usr/local/share/gnuplot/4.4/lua/gnuplot-tikz.lua:252: bad argument #7 to 'format' (string expected, got no value)
stack

gnuplot>
```

---

I have also tried to install homebrew from https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation although I did not do the Java Developer Update - is that necessary?
Now 'brew install gnuplot' gives problems with the glib dependency

```
hpek@melda:~$ brew install glib
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:43: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/local/bin/brew:74: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:7: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.28/glib-2.28.8.tar.bz2
File already downloaded in /Users/hpek/Library/Caches/Homebrew
==> Downloading patches

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
/usr/bin/patch: **** Can't open patch file 001-homebrew.diff : No such file or directory
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/patch -f -p0 -i 001-homebrew.diff
hpek@melda:~$
```

When I install gnuplot manually, am I suppose to know about and install all these dependencies myself?

Comment: Do you have latex and tikz installed on your system?  Have you checked the output of `./configure` to see if it explains why it can't enable the tikz terminal?

Comment: Yes I have MacTeX with working TikZ. There is only this one line in config.log concerning TikZ that I can see.

Comment: Have you tried greping for lua in the log?  I think you need lua and its development headers installed.

Comment: I think you are rigth - there are 16 lines with the word lua e.g.`ld: library not found for -llua`. What is lua, and where do I get it?

Comment: I have now completely rewritten my question to reflect my progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
brew update
```

then try it again. This appears to be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the 252 (or 254 in my version) of the LUA script is using a format command with less argument than necessary. Adding a "X" as #5 argument (a.k.a. script revision number) solves this.

Here is my new code in the script:

```
gp.write(string.format("%%%% generated with GNUPLOT %sp%s (%s; terminal rev. %s, script rev. %s)\n%%%% %s\n",
      term.gp_version, term.gp_patchlevel,
      string.sub(term.lua_term_revision,7,-3),"x",
      pgf.REVISION,os.date()))
```

I guess there is better to do if I knew where to find the script revision number.